# ClickOnce App says requires .NET 3.5 when built using .NET 2.0

Tags: .net, clickonce

Help!

I have a clickonce app built and published using .Net 2.0. This app has a number of .Net dll's all built using .Net 2.0. However when I publish the app, and try to install it I get a message saying that version 3.5 of .Net is required!

I've tried my best to track down what component could require .Net 3.5, first by checking and rebuilding everything, and then using ILDASM to look at the file headers. Can't find anything relating to .Net 3.5 at all and I am at my wits end!

Any ideas how to resolve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try changing the "Required Components" (not sure whether that is the exact term - using German VS2008) on the "Publish" tab in the project properties. .NET 3.5 might still be marked as a required component, even though it should be .NET 2.0.

Comment: That must have happened when I initially deployed the app as a .Net 3.5 those pre-requisites must have been automatically selected, but even though I changed it to .Net 2.0 VS2008 did not de-select those components automatically,

Answer (score 0):

Have you targeted the 2.0 framework in the project properties? I can't remember the exact option as I'm not in front of my dev machine at the moment but it's in there somewhere...

Comment: Yes, all dlls target .net 2.0